# Yii Retrieve and store in a variable a renderPartial file

Tags: yii

I have a php file under protected/views/directory_controller_name with formatting like that

```
<p>
<?php echo $model->title;?>
</p>
...
```

I display the file with classic method in the controller :

```
$this->render('filename',array('model'=>$model));
```

But know, I need to send an email with the same template/layout so I want to store the render of the file in an variable like

$msgHTML = $this->renderInternal('_items', array('model'=>$model));

```
But it doesn't work!
```

How can I get render view from a file and store in a variable?
Is it possible?

I don't want to use:

```
$msgHTML = '<p>'.$model->title.'</p>'
...
```

Because the file is very long and I don't want to duplicate code!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$msgHTML = $this->renderInternal('_items', array('model'=>$model), true);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CBaseController#renderInternal-detail

Comment: finally I use this : $msgHTML = $this->renderFile('protected/views/modelname/_items.php', array('model' => $model), TRUE);

Comment: yep, you're right, renderInternal requires full path/filename including extension - i only added the third argument addressing the main issue, tx for clarification.

Answer (score 18):

Don't use the renderInternal method, use [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail) instead. Render internal is low level method and should not be used in such context. To catch the output just set the $return parameter to true:

```
<?php $output = $this->renderPartial('_subView', $dataArray, true); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I might be missing something, but can't you just use regular render() with the return argument set to true?  Then you can just use a view 'name' instead of knowing the path.  (And unless my trusty stack trace logger is broken, renderFile and renderInternal take the same fully qualified path argument.  At least I can see renderPartial() passing the full path to my view file to renderFile.)

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with these ways

1) if you want to get the output with header and footer (i.e ) full layout then do this

```
//add true in the last parameter if you want a return of the output 
$htmloutput=$this->render('_pdfoutput',array('data'=>'nothing'),true);
```

2) similarly if you don't want to get the layout files just use `renderpartial` in the same way

```
$htmloutput=$this->renderpartial('_pdfoutput',array('data'=>'nothing'),true);
```

you will get the html of files in the variable . use this anywhere